# NokiaHERE Api -> Missing authentication parameters

Tags: php, curl, here-api

I want to get some data about a place in a city with Nokia Here maps. Therefore I wanted to perform a cuRL Request. I'm building the cURL Request like that:

```
$postFields                 = array ( "app_id" => self::APP_ID, "app_code" => self::APP_CODE, "at" => $latLon['lat'] . "," .$latLon['lon'], "q" => $term, "pretty" => "true");
$this->_curl->setUrl        ( $this->getUrl() );
$this->_curl->setPostField  ( $postFields );
$curlResults                = $this->_curl->execute();
var_dump ( $curlResults );
```

But when I do this in my browser I get

`"{"status":401,"message":"Missing authentication parameters"}"`

However, when I print out the whole stuff. Like building the query with

`echo $this->getUrl() . "?app_id=" . self::APP_ID, "&app_code=" . self::APP_CODE . "&at=" . $latLon['lat'] . "," .$latLon['lon'] . "&q=" . $term . "&pretty=" . "true";`

it works without any problems. Why is Nokia telling me I'm missing authentication parameters?

This right here is the query string

`http://places.nlp.nokia.com/places/v1/discover/search?app_id=XXXXXXX&app_code=XXXXXXX&at=51.2151915838703%2C6.76354323416523&q=Rewe&pretty=true`

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't provided a way to test it out ourselves, I assume they don't support `$_POST` on their end, which is what you're doing.

Try the following:

```
$postFields                 = array ( "app_id" => self::APP_ID, "app_code" => self::APP_CODE, "at" => $latLon['lat'] . "," .$latLon['lon'], "q" => $term, "pretty" => "true");
$this->_curl->setUrl        ( $this->getUrl() . '?' . http_build_query( $postFields ) );
//$this->_curl->setPostField  ( $postFields );
$curlResults                = $this->_curl->execute();
var_dump ( $curlResults );
```

This will perform a GET request, which works (according to you).

Comment: Then again, I'm getting the same error. Here is my query / of course without my app ids and codes 

`http://places.nlp.nokia.com/places/v1/discover/search?app_id=xxxxxx&app_code=xxxxxxx&at=51.2151915838703%2C6.76354323416523&q=Rewe&pretty=true`

When I do that manually on their site it works, but when I do it with cURL it tells me the same error.

Comment: But I guess I see the error. Instead of a `,` (comma) there's `%2C` - Is there a way to not let it be a `,`?

Comment: Use the function `urlencode` to encode the parts of the url that should be encoded. This will encode the `,` (comma) as well.

Comment: Hey, just did that. Problem was the same. Always telling me that the authentication parameters are missing. I even tried to do it by hand (setting the url etc.) and still the same... :/ I wonder where the problem here is

Answer (score 0):

Due to missing context (how are you setting self::APP_ID and self::APP_CODE?) and lack of PHP knowledge, I cannot solve your problem.

But it might help your search that the error message "Missing authentication params" indicates that the request generated by curl is missing the app_id or the app_code parameter or both as opposed to a wrong app_id which (in the current implementation) would give an error message "Invalid app_id app_code combination".

Examples:

http://places.nlp.nokia.com/places/v1/discover/search?app_code=xxxxxxx&at=51.2151915838703%2C6.76354323416523&q=Rewe&pretty=true

returns a 401 with message "Missing authentication parameters" whereas

http://places.nlp.nokia.com/places/v1/discover/search?app_id=xxxxxx&app_code=xxxxxxx&at=51.2151915838703%2C6.76354323416523&q=Rewe&pretty=true

returns a 401 with message "Invalid app_id app_code combination".

Comment: Hey. I "solved" it. I just requested a new app code and app id and with that it worked. Seems like there was a problem with Nokia Here that they somehow didn't recognize my app id and app code

I'm setting `self::APP_ID` at the beginning of the class by `const APP_ID = 'xxxxx'`

Answer (score 0):

I "solved" it, by just requesting a new App Id and App Code. Don't know why the previous didn't work, but now I don't have any major problems. For any curious. My request now looks like this (I tried to make it as simple as possible )

`$getString  = $this->getUrl() . $this->getAuthString() . "&at=" . $where['lat'] . "," . $where['lon'] . "&q=" . $term . "&pretty=true&size=100";`